# How to find specific blob in my container

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to access a specific blob in my containers but I try some different ways but I want to learn what is the best way for find a specific blob in container. Here is my code :

```
            var game = Get<Game>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);

            var account = CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("blobConnection");

            var container = account
                                   .CreateCloudBlobClient()
                                   .GetContainerReference("gamehtmls");

            var blobUri = container.ListBlobs().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Uri.ToString().ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower()));

            var blobName = blobUri.Uri.AbsolutePath.Replace("/gamehtmls/", "");

            var blob = container.GetBlobReference(String.Format("{0}index.html", blobName));
            blob.Properties.ContentType = "text/html";
```

and also In this container I have two games which names : Galactians and Galactians2 so My code doesn't work for this games .

Does anyone have advice for me ?

Thank you ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is more an issue with how you're searching for the directory than a problem with Azure.

String.Contains will match any directories containing the string 'Galactians' with 'Galactians ', 'Galactians2' and 'my cat is named Galactians99'.  Maybe just...

```
var blobUri = container.ListBlobs().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Uri.ToString().ToLower() == name.ToLower());
```

...will match the name exactly or even String.StartsWith if there's some extra chars you cannot detect.

Comment: First of all thank you but I tried your suggestion and Uri.ToString() returns full path [link](http://blob.core.windows.net/gamehtmls/Avatar/index.html) so It doesn't match game name which is Avatar :/ I tried this code : 'code' container.ListBlobs()
                                       .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Uri.AbsolutePath.ToLower().Replace("/gamehtmls/", "").Replace("/", "") == name.ToLower());  and It works but I don't know It is true , I think Is there any better way than my code

Comment: You just need to format and compare the appropriate strings.  StartsWith, Replace will help you.  You can utilise the Uri object and break it into an array and compare the last item, i.e. x.Uri.Segments[theUpperBound].